# utilizar hilos y al compilar no utilizar -l pthread

Tags: c, hilos

Hola estoy haciendo un programa en linux con hilos y cuando compilo debo usar gcc .... -l pthread para que funcione
mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que no tenga que estar poniendo el pthread siempre
simplemente compilar como gcc -o prueba prueba.c

ojala se entienda, saludos

Comment: Puedes usar `alias` o `function` de _Bash_ (o el equivalente en la _shell_ que utilices), o, mi recomendación, usa un [Makefile](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make).

Comment: Gracias amigo, lo otro lo busque y entendí, pero lo del alias no encuentro info, podrias aclararlo por favor

Comment: [Aquí](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-useful-bash-aliases-and-functions) tienes un buen tutorial sobre `alias` y `function`. Está en inglés, pero solo siguiendo los ejemplos creo que es suficiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa un Makefile come este:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g
LDFLAGS=-g -pthread
DEPS = func.h
OBJ = main.o func.o 

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS

miprog: $(OBJ)
    gcc -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
```

El anterior makefile supone que tienes tres ficheros:
main.c
func.c
func.h

Si tienes más o menos ficheros ajústalo de forma apropiada.
Los .h has de ponerlos en `DEPS`.
Por cada .c que tengas has de poner un .o en OBJ puesto que primero se compilan y luego se enlazan.
En `CFLAGS` pon las opciones que uses para compilar. Por ejemplo -g si haces depuración.
En `LDFLAGS` pones las opciones de enlazado. En este caso -lpthread.
Y en `CC` pones el compilador que usas.

Pon este fichero llamado Makefile en el mismo directorio que tu código fuente. Y para compilarlo basta con ejecutar:

```
make
```

Comment: Gracias amigo :D me quedó claro.